# Trying to wrap my head around *args in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, args

I'm reading about `*args` and `**kwargs` in Python, and am experimenting in the REPL:

```
varX, *varY = [99, 100, 101]
```

I was expecting `varX` to be `[99, 100, 101]`, but that's not what happened.  Instead I get this:

```
print(varX)
# 99
```

Huh?  Well then what is `varY`?

```
print(varY)
# [100, 101]
```

Getting the list makes sense, but I thought it would have three values, and not two.

```
print(*varY)
# 100 101
```

At least this makes sense to me based on all of the stuff that's happened before.  So my big question is why is Python (3.6) making the original assignments in this manner?

Comment: It's called unpacking.  You unpack a single value into `varX`, and then use the `*splat` operator to unpack everything else into `varY`.  You could also use `x, y, z = [1,2,3]` to unpack each value of the list into each of your three variables.

Comment: See the PEP introducing this feature here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Comment: Interesting. Your title and introduction have nothing to do with the meat of the question. Different type of unpacking.

Comment: Was expecting a question on functions when I saw the title

Comment: I have to say, dupe hammer feels nice. Please let me know if the duplicate is missing something from what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @user3483203 is trying to say - with some examples. 
You can pack and pack tuples into a single variable or unpack a tuple into several variables.

Say you have `t = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` you can unpack this by `v, w, x, y, z = t` this will assign each respecting index to the return variable so `v = 1, w = 2` and so on. This is called unpacking "you are unpacking `t` into `v, w, x, y, z`. You can also pack variables together. Say you have `v = 1, w = 2, x = 3, y = 4, z = 5` you can do the following `t = [v, w, x, y, z]`.

This is just a brief explanation on packing and unpacking.

Comment: What about splat? Also, technically true for all iterable, not just tuples. Even works for generators.

Comment: I have not used `*splat` so I cannot comment.

Comment: Ah, but that's what the question is about.